# Hot Deck Imputation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, imputation

I have been trying to find Python code that would allow me to replace missing values in a dataframe's column. The focus of my analysis is in biostatistics so I am not comfortable with replacing values using means/medians/modes. I would like to apply the ["Hot Deck Imputation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)#Hot-deck) method.

I cannot find any Python functions or packages online that takes the column of a dataframe and fills missing values with the "Hot Deck Imputation" method.

I did, however, see this [GitHub project](https://github.com/tarikbir/missing_data_imputation) and *did not* find it useful.

The following is an example of some of my data (assume this is a pandas dataframe):

```
| age | sex | bmi  | anesthesia score | pain level |
|-----|-----|------|------------------|------------|
| 78  | 1   | 40.7 | 3                | 0          |
| 55  | 1   | 25.3 | 3                | 0          |
| 52  | 0   | 25.4 | 3                | 0          |
| 77  | 1   | 44.9 | 3                | 3          |
| 71  | 1   | 26.3 | 3                | 0          |
| 39  | 0   | 28.2 | 2                | 0          |
| 82  | 1   | 27   | 2                | 1          |
| 70  | 1   | 37.9 | 3                | 0          |
| 71  | 1   | NA   | 3                | 1          |
| 53  | 0   | 24.5 | 2                | NA         |
| 68  | 0   | 34.7 | 3                | 0          |
| 57  | 0   | 30.7 | 2                | 0          |
| 40  | 1   | 22.4 | 2                | 0          |
| 73  | 1   | 34.2 | 2                | 0          |
| 66  | 1   | NA   | 3                | 1          |
| 55  | 1   | 42.6 | NA               | NA         |
| 53  | 0   | 37.5 | 3                | 3          |
| 65  | 0   | 31.6 | 2                | 2          |
| 36  | 0   | 29.6 | 1                | 0          |
| 60  | 0   | 25.7 | 2                | NA         |
| 70  | 1   | 30   | NA               | NA         |
| 66  | 1   | 28.3 | 2                | 0          |
| 63  | 1   | 29.4 | 3                | 2          |
| 70  | 1   | 36   | 3                | 2          |
```

I would like to apply a Python function that would allow me to input a column as a parameter and return the column with the missing values replaced with imputed values using the "Hot Deck Imputation" method.

I am using this for the purpose of statistical modeling with models such as linear and logistic regression using `Statsmodels.api`. I am not using this for Machine Learning.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Would [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) or [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) do? Which should be a type of "Hot Code Imputation" (LOCF)

Comment: How are the two methods different and how do I know that they use the Hot Code Imputation?

Comment: The `ffill` uses `last observation carried forward` LOCF Hot Code Imputation.

Comment: Is there possibly a more precise way of filling the missing values, excluding means/modes/medians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ffill` that uses `last observation carried forward` (LOCF) Hot Code Imputation.

```py
#...
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Scikit-learn impute offers KNN, Mean, Max and other imputing methods. (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html)

```py
# sklearn '>=0.22.x'
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")

DF['imputed_x'] = imputer.fit_transform(DF[['bmi']])

print(DF['imputed_x'])
```

Comment: Yes, give me a second. I will add examples

Comment: I tried the code that you shared: 
```impute = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")```
```DF['imputed_x'] = DF['bmi'].apply(lambda y: impute.fit_tranform(y),axis=0)```
```print(DF['imputed_x'])```

The following were the errors that I got:
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Let me test it.

Comment: Fixed. See that `df[['x']]`. Getting DataFrame and not series

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the help! Can you please explain how to determine the best value for "n_neighbors"?

Comment: that depends on your data. Try other imputers too, like `SimpleImputer` with different strategies (median, most frequent, ...) see what you get