# Pandas dropna() with many NaNs in all columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe with several hundered rows and columns and want to drop all NaNs.
Unfortunatly there are NaNs in all columns and all rows.

```
df = df.dropna(how = "any")
```

would therefore result in an empty dataframe.
I use a while loop to iteratively dropnan columns with a threshhold.

```py
i = 0
while df.isna().sum().sum() != 0:
    i += 0.01
    df= df.dropna(thresh=(i * df.shape[0]), axis= 0)
    df= df.dropna(thresh=(i * df.shape[1]), axis= 1)
```

This greedy algoritm is in more than one way for sure a sub optimal solution.
Aside from writing my own linear program to minimize deleted data, is there maybe a build in fuction that I do not know?
My goal is to preserve as much data as possible.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to drop rows and columns with NaNs? Especially why is it ok to preserve some rows and columns with less than a given number of NaNs?

Comment: The long term goal is to apply a regression task, where the algorithms cant handle NaN values. I also already experimented with .fillna(), but because of the amount of nans in my dataset I fear potential quality loss. 
Regarding your second questions. I do not quite understand what you mean. When the while loop is left, there are no NaNs left.

Answer (score 0):

Given your motivation in the comments, I can recommend you to try using `interpolate()` method of Pandas.

```
df = df.interpolate()
```

You can experiment with different methods of interpolation using the `method`.

As an example, you can use

```
df = df.interpolate(method='quadratic')
```

if you have time-series data that is growing at an increased rate.
(Note that you have to have `scipy` installed to use the `method` argument.)

Please refer to the Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html).

Furthermore, you can try to experiment with other data imputation methods.
Some data imputation methods are explained in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-nan-values-62d50f738fc) article.

Especially, [Hot Deck imputation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541759/hot-deck-imputation-in-python) might work in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effords. 
This would probabily help most people in a simular situation as mine. 
My datapoints unfortunatly are uncorrilated. Therefore interpolation is not the write way to go.

Comment: Sorry I could not help. But take a look at Hot Deck imputation that searches for a similar instance (doner) and replaces the missing value with the value of the doner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541759/hot-deck-imputation-in-python